# How to stop Traefik stop SSL Termination

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

By default looks like Traefik terminates the SSL and webserver only sees the http request. As a result I'm getting this error below when trying to set Auth cookie on asp.net form

```
These cookies require the browser to issue the request over SSL (https protocol)
```

I tried below on web site label but no luck. How do we stop Traefik terminating SSL?

```
labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.stsSeconds=31536000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.rule=Host(`${CM_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.middlewares=force-STS-Header"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.cm-secure.rule=HostSNI(`${CM_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.cm-secure.entrypoints=https" 
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.cm-secure.tls.passthrough=true"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.cm-secure.service=cm"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.cm-secure.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
```